# How to download all files and folders from artifactory using curl command?

Tags: script, python, curl

We are using artifactory for uploading and downloading project dependencies. Able to upload the required content using curl script having parameter "--upload-file". Now, I want to download required file and folders from artifactory, is there any curl command exists for this ??

There is an argument "-compressed" from which we can compress the content and get the decompressed stuff as an output. I tried it but unable to get the expected result.

Below is the command I have used :-

```
curl -k -u USERNAME:PASSWORD -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip" -i 
"https://ARTIFACTORY-URL/list/REPOSITORY-NAME/DEPENDENCIES-PATH5/
```

Getting output in html format as below :-

```
Date: Thu, 05 Jul 2018 07:34:53 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Server: Artifactory/5.9.1
X-Artifactory-Id: xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
X-Artifactory-Node-Id: prodmast
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, DELETE, PUT
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, Content-Type, X-Codingpedia
Cache-Control: no-store
Artifactory-UI-messages: []
SessionValid: false

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<html>
<head><title>Index of REPOSITORY-NAME/DEPENDENCIES-PATH</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Index of REPOSITORY-NAME/DEPENDENCIES-PATH</h1>
<pre>Name                                  Last modified      Size</pre><hr/>
<pre>  <a href="../">../</a>
<a href="dpAddinNT/">dpAddinNT/</a>       04-Jul-2018 03:07    -
<a href="qlxLib/">qlxLib/</a>             04-Jul-2018 03:08    -
<a href="xiDplServer/">xiDplServer/</a>   04-Jul-2018 03:17    -
<a href="ADSlib.txt">ADSlib.txt</a>       22-May-2018 03:49   328 bytes
<a href="xyz.dll">xyz.dll</a>             25-May-2018 02:45   18.69 KB
<a href="abc.dll">abc.dll</a>             25-May-2018 02:45   18.19 KB
<a href="def.dll">def.dll</a>             25-May-2018 02:45   18.19 KB
<a href="ghi.dll">ghi.dll</a>             25-May-2018 02:45   18.19 KB
```

Kindly suggest here....!!

Comment: What this have to do with Python?